# How to ground a 2 prong plug electronic?

Tags: mains, grounding

I am installing a strip of 110v led strip outdoors and placing them on an aluminum channel. I will be cutting the strip, waterproofing them and placing different sections of the strip throughout the channel.

What I am worried about the most is eventually the weathering may/will cause a short or ground fault, and it will become dangerous to touch the aluminum channel.

From what I see the led strip is powered via mains to a rectified 110v DC, and only comes with a 2 prong plug.

Is there anyway to wire/rewire the led strip such that it can detect a ground fault from a 3 prong outlet.

Comment: Will it be compliant to insulation breakdown construction and tests with double insulation ? If No then non-compliant

Comment: lookup GFCI ....

Comment: You could always tap in a screw and attach a ground wire to the aluminum channel and run that back to a hard ground somewhere or change the plug to a three prong and run the wire there. It wont be pretty though.

Comment: FWIW ,I installed 20m of 12V indoor stripleds outdoors and applied polyurethane and stuck under wood trim on fence perimeter. So far so good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a three-conductor cable or the two-conductor cable you have with an additional separate earth conductor. Route live and neutral to your LED strip. Terminate the earth conductor to a crimped, not soldered, ring terminal. Drill a hole in the channel. Clean the hole, surrounding area, and terminal with fine abrasives. Clean the whole bond area and all hardware with alcohol. Assemble the ground stud onto the aluminum and seal the area with outdoor silicone. Be sure to use zinc-plated hardware to avoid galvanic issues caused by dissimilar metal contact in the outdoor environment. Use a GFCI as well.

Is this up to code? I don't know. Is it safe? Yes.

The intended function of the earth connection is to ensure that large current flows when a short circuit occurs, causing protective devices like circuit breakers to activate. The intended function of circuit breakers is to prevent fires caused by overheated wires, but they have the added bonus of ensuring that grounded equipment cannot become energized and pose a hazard to humans.

A GFCI trips if current flow to earth is detected, such as may happen while someone is receiving a shock, to protect human beings.

Comment: Ya I was going to suggest that too, but it concerns me the OP will make matters worse since this is for outdoors and presumably what he has is already hermetic. Breaking into the cable may be bad advice. Hence my comment to run a discrete ground line.

Comment: @Trevor_G - I hadn't considered that. Updated my answer.

Comment: @vofa - Could I use something like a grounding plug/cord (not adapter, just a plug connected only to ground) connected to the same GFCI outlet and use that as the discrete ground line?

Comment: @snoopy3321 That sounds reasonable. The only thing that really matters is that you end up with a solid, reliable path between the exposed metal and earth.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to protect against leakage to the aluminum channel is to install a Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter (GFCI) - also known as a Residual Current Detector (RCD) in the AC power supply to the LED strip.

This will protect anyone who might be subject to electric shock.

[Edit] A GFCI works by monitoring the current difference between the Line and Neutral lines. If a leakage path develops from the Line lead to Ground, the GFCI detects that difference and trips.

Comment: The outlet I am plugging into already is a GFCI outlet, but the plug I am using is only a 2 prong so it won't have a ground connection. I am trying to find the defacto way to handling shorts and ground faults given only a two prong device, and somehow connecting the ground conductor.

Comment: @snoopy3321 the CGFI will work even without a ground wire back to the outlet if the 110V shorts to real ground somewhere. Of course that may be through you so the 25mS it takes the CGFI to open may be a tad toxic.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is outdoors you probably should not mess with the wiring. The driver itself needs either to be meant to be used outdoors or enclosed in a hermetically sealed electrical box.

Since it does not have it's own ground you should take steps to add one.

Tap and wire a separate ground line either back to the outlet or direct to another grounding point (gas meter, metal water pipe). Wherever your channel is broken, say to go round corners, you need a ground strap to electrically join the parts back together.

Ultimately, you would be better to use low voltage LED strips that are intended to be used outdoors.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarification Trevor. FYI the leds and driver are made to be IP68 waterproof, but not certified for underwater use, which I'm not going to do anyways. They are also made very poorly which I am willing to take the extra steps to make it safer.